# SYS Date in Oracle

Tags: rest, spring-boot, oracle10g, dto, microservices

I have a microservice and I use REST methods such as GET PUT POST, for this issue lets take an example POST !
I want to add a record to one table, but I need to only add two values and the remaining two are id and date. ID is auto increment and have used Sequence Generator, hence working even if I do not give an ID as input.

I would like to do the same for Date but would like to not input date plus make sure the date set for that record is the SYS Date in the Oracle DB, I have made Date variable default as SYSDate in DB but its still not taking in a null value as its not null. How do I implement this ?

Help is truly appreciated !

Comment: You've tagged this for Oracle 10g which did not have an identity column.  Perhaps you mean that you created a trigger on the table that uses a sequence to populate the primary key column.  If so, perhaps you just want to modify the trigger to also assign the `sysdate` to your date column.  If that's not what you're looking for, however, it would help to provide an example-- presumably there is some SQL statement that you want to do X but is actually doing Y.  We'd need to know the statement, X, and Y.

Comment: I am implementing this functionality without trigger, but has just set the date variable constraint default to sysdate in DB. As one more constraint is 'notnull' I am not able to access the sysdate as user input has null date values.

Comment: Then I am confused.  Oracle 10g would have no way to create an auto incrementing ID without a trigger.  Your `insert` statement could explicitly reference a sequence's `nextval` in which case it could also explicitly reference `sysdate`.  Not knowing what your actual SQL looks like, it's hard to guess what you are really doing.

Comment: As I am not using SQL statement, I am not able to show it here. I am doing everything in SQLDeveloper. I did the SequenceGenerator and Sequence GenerationType in the backend code in the model class. In the DB I have added a constraint for Date as sysdate.

Comment: So... have the model class set the date; or have it not refer to the column so it doesn't try to insert null and override the default (maybe not practical, if you need to read existing values), or add a trigger to set the date on insert. Since you still haven't given any details in your question it isn't clear what your best option is.

Comment: The model class has the date attribute and has been referred to the column but no value has been set nor null !